# .NET core web api send bad request to client

Tags: asp.net-core

I am writing a web api in a .net core web project.

```
// POST: api/Companies
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        // inform the client that request is incorrect.
    }
}
```

I want to be able to inform the client that its a bad request, I found many articles but all were 1-2 years old, I am sure a lot has changed since then. So wanted to know the best solution for this problem.

Comment: return BadRequest(YourObject);

Comment: No, it hasn't changed, API functions on HTTP protocol, and the bad request and its status code hasn't changed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The BadRequest method, declared in the ControllerBase class, will create a 400 response message. It's been around for years (new versions, almost same implementation) and it's solid, so use that

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        return BadRequest("request is incorrect");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be good to actually return that response; changing the return type of function too. :-)

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan thanks for pointing that out, updated the answer :)

Comment: Can I use this in an HttpGet as well?

Comment: @Enrico Yes you can :)

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to do this is by changing your method signature to:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        return BadRequest("Value must be passed in the request body.");
    }
    else
    {
        return Ok("Request was correct");
    }
}
```

By returning a IHttpActionResult you can call the `Ok(...) method`, the `BadRequest("reason")`, and other built-in types like you can find on [the HttpActionResult documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inform the client that it's a bad request then you need to make some changes in your method signature.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        return BadRequest("Invalid input data");
    }else{
//return the result of the action

}
}
```

Your controller class must be inherited from ControllerBase class and it consists of BadRequest method which gives 400 response. A "Bad Request" is an HTTP response status code that indicates that the server cannot process the request due to a client error.

IActionResult - In ASP.NET Core, you can use IActionResult to return different types of action results, including views, JSON, status codes, and more.